Problema con Keycloak
Estoy intentando intregar keycloak a mi proyecto de microservicios pero tengo el siguiente problema.
Los clientes Feign no tienen acceso de autenticación a otros servicios. Esto se debe a que los tokens de autenticación solo están disponibles para el servicio al que se les pasa el token junto con la solicitud API. Este problema está causando que el order-service deje de funcionar, y sugiere que la integración con Keycloak debe implementarse manualmente en el order-service para resolver el problema.
Lo que intete fue esto pero solamente obtengo en mi postman una respuesta de un HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Please sign in</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-oOE/3m0LUMPub4kaC09mrdEhIc+e3exm4xOGxAmuFXhBNF4hcg/6MiAXAf5p0P56" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login with OAuth 2.0</h2>
        <table class="table table-striped">
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

Este es mi codigo:
La configuracion de mi order-service de seguridad
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          customer:
            clientId: micro-services-api
            clientSecret: OdO4lkxnfeWSemvbWPLrFXoX3ohvzXt2
            authorizationGrantType: client_credentials
            token-uri: http://localhost:9098/realms/micro-services/protocol/openid-connect/token
            scope:
              - openid
        provider:
          customer:
            tokenUri: http://localhost:9098/realms/micro-services/protocol/openid-connect/token

package com.lautaro.ecommerce.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
/
/Esta configuración registrará el interceptor Feign que añadirá el token OAuth2 a las solicitudes salientes.
@Configuration
public class FeignConfig {

    @Bean
    public FeignOAuth2Interceptor feignOAuth2Interceptor() {
        return new FeignOAuth2Interceptor();
    }
}


package com.lautaro.ecommerce.config;

import feign.RequestInterceptor;
import feign.RequestTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizeRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

//Este interceptor se asegurará de que cada solicitud Feign desde order-service hacia otro servicio tenga un token de autorización válido.
@Component
public class FeignOAuth2Interceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager;

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = authorizedClientManager.authorize(
                OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("customer")
                        .principal("micro-services-api")
                        .build());

        if (client != null) {
            template.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
        }
    }
}

package com.lautaro.ecommerce.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;

//Esta clase configura cómo se gestionan los clientes OAuth2 autorizados y proporciona un OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager que es necesario para obtener los tokens.
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

        return new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
    }
}

